# For loop in R, getting the ith and ith+j row entry in a colum

Tags: r, for-loop

I've got a data table and I want to go into column "x" and get the *ith* value and the *ith + j* value, given they meet a condition

Say i've got the following data table "z":

```
     z
      weight height   length
 1: 9.436635      1 79.16808
 2: 6.452202      0 86.33170
 3: 4.639220      1 60.52781
 4: 7.941667      1 33.79673
 5: 3.135519      1 68.47615
 6: 7.918595      1 69.77795
 7: 3.950212      1 49.74780
 8: 7.109392      0 58.41541
 9: 5.783499      0 51.30477
10: 5.056078      1 78.37624
11: 9.436635      1 51.69053
12: 6.452202      0 18.39108
13: 4.639220      1 48.52367
14: 7.941667      1 20.99888
15: 3.135519      1 29.77180
```

I want to write something which will give me the first value in the height column and the second value based on the following condition.

I want to write a loop like:

```
list1 <- list()
> for (i in -1:nrow(z)){
+     list[[i]] <- z[height == 1 & height+i == 0,]
+ }
```

So what I want is to get the occurrences where height ==1 and then the immediately following height == 0. I however have found that I can't write a loop like this.

Essentially I want all the rows where I have a 1 followed by a 0 in the height column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `data.table` methods as well by comparing the 'ith' element of 'height' equal to 1 with the 'i+1' equal to 0 (using `shift` with `type = "lead"`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[height==1 & shift(height, type = "lead")==0]
```

If we need the row 'i' with 'i+1', we can get the row index (`.I`) based on the logical condition, then use `rep` to get the next row and subset the dataset.

```
i1 <- setDT(df1)[,.I[height==1 & shift(height, type = "lead", fill = 1)==0]]
df1[rep(i1, each=2) + 0:1]
 #    weight height   length
 #1: 9.436635      1 79.16808
 #2: 6.452202      0 86.33170
 #3: 3.950212      1 49.74780
 #4: 7.109392      0 58.41541
 #5: 9.436635      1 51.69053
 #6: 6.452202      0 18.39108
```

Comment: Sorry if it's a silly question, but what does .I do?

Comment: @Gin_Salmon We get the logical `TRUE/FALSE` vector with (`height ==1 & ...`).  By using `.I`, we get the row index. i.e. similar to `which(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))`, however, `.I` will be very useful when we are doing a group by operation.  If we do `which`, it gives only the index of row within a group, but `.I` gives the actual row index based on the entire dataset.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
df2 <- df1[df1$height==1 & c(diff(df1$height),0)==-1,]
#> df2
#      weight height   length
#1:  9.436635      1 79.16808
#7:  3.950212      1 49.74780
#11: 9.436635      1 51.69053
```

---

*Edit:*

Following the clarification by the OP in some comments, it appears that the line immediately *after* the one that fulfills the criterion should be selected, too. One possibility to achieve this could be

```
idx <- which(df1$height == 1 & c(diff(df1$height), 0) == -1)
df1[sort(c(idx,idx+1)),]
#      weight height   length
# 1: 9.436635      1 79.16808
# 2: 6.452202      0 86.33170
# 7: 3.950212      1 49.74780
# 8: 7.109392      0 58.41541
#11: 9.436635      1 51.69053
#12: 6.452202      0 18.39108
```

**data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(weight = c(9.436635, 6.452202, 4.63922, 7.941667, 
3.135519, 7.918595, 3.950212, 7.109392, 5.783499, 5.056078, 9.436635, 
6.452202, 4.63922, 7.941667, 3.135519), height = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), length = c(79.16808, 
86.3317, 60.52781, 33.79673, 68.47615, 69.77795, 49.7478, 58.41541, 
51.30477, 78.37624, 51.69053, 18.39108, 48.52367, 20.99888, 29.7718
)), .Names = c("weight", "height", "length"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1:", "2:", "3:", "4:", "5:", "6:", "7:", "8:", "9:", "10:", 
"11:", "12:", "13:", "14:", "15:"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the rows where `height==1` and **immediately** afterwards `height==0`, you can use `filter` from the `dplyr` package with `lead` and `lag`

```
library(dplyr)
result <- z %>% filter((height==1 & lead(height)==0) | (height==0 & lag(height)==1))
```

`filter` keeps only the rows that satisfy the condition. The results, using your data is:

```
print(result)
##    weight height   length
##1 9.436635      1 79.16808
##2 6.452202      0 86.33170
##3 3.950212      1 49.74780
##4 7.109392      0 58.41541
##5 9.436635      1 51.69053
##6 6.452202      0 18.39108
```

Comment: Hi @aichao, this is exactly what I'm after unfortunately I need it in data.table. Do you know any way of getting this result but in data.table?

Comment: @Gin_Salmon: akrun updated his answer, so that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it using the `which` function:

```
db<-data.frame(height=c(1,0,1,1,1,10,1,0,1,0))

for (i in 1:length(db$height)){
  print(which(db$height[i]==1 & db$height[i+1]==0))

}
```

This will give you the first occurrence of such pattern.